# In python, an object class scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix with a .T Method, what does the .T stand for?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy, nltk

**In the fallowing code:**

```
# Initializes variable to class, empty BoW vector
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
# Creates a BoW matrix 
bow_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(processed_articles)

#  ----------------- Stores BoW vectors results in a DataFrame

# Gets vocabulary of terms
feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
# Creates an articles index
articles_index = [f"Aticle {i+1}" for i in range(len(articles))]
# Creates pandas DataFrame with the features names
# The .T
df_bag_of_words = pd.DataFrame(bow_matrix.T.todense(), index=feature_names, columns=articles_index)
```

**What does the** *.T* **in** *bow_matrix.T.todense()* **stand for?**
My understanding is *numpy.ndarray.T* stand for *self.transpose()* in a *numpy.ndarray* object, but the *bow_matrix* object is a *scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix* object..

Comment: FYI you should have tagged this numpy/scipy since the matrix is from `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix`, not nltk or base Python.

Comment: Scipy sparse tries to look a lot like `np.matrix`, though it is a separate package and class(s)

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.transpose.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.transpose

Comment: Welcome to SO. [You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on the big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can also upvote answers by clicking on the upper gray triangle.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354584/teaching-new-users-how-to-accept-an-answer)

Answer (score 0):

**`.T`** is a synonym for [**`transpose()`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html). It's actually a scipy/numpy method of a matrix.

The matrix is from `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix`, not nltk or base Python.